# Why does my lazy filtered list in scheme consume so much memory?

Tags: scheme, lazy-evaluation, implementation, lazy-sequences, chez-scheme

I'm currently learning to use some slightly more advanced features of scheme, and I've hit a road-block with lazy lists.

Basically, I'm trying to create an infinite, lazily generated list, and apply a lazy filter on it, and only take a single element. My hope was that this would consume very little memory: the filter looks at only one element at a time, and there's no need to store the previous entries. Here is my attempt at this:

```
(define lazy-inf-seq
  (lambda (start next)
    (delay (cons start (lazy-inf-seq (next start) next)))))

(define lazy-arithmetic-sequence
  (lambda (start d)
    (lazy-inf-seq start (lambda (v) (+ v d)))))

(define lazy-filter
  (lambda (pred seq)
    (delay
      (let loop ([sequence seq])
        (let ([forced (force sequence)])
          (cond [(null? forced) '()]
                [(pred (car forced))
                 (cons (car forced) (lazy-filter pred (cdr forced)))]
                [else (loop (cdr forced))]))))))
```

So, to be clear, a "lazy list" here is a procedure that, when `(force)`d, produces `(head . tail)`, where `head` is one of the values on the list, and `tail` is the rest of the list (that needs to be forced in turn). I don't know if this is a "standard" lazy list in scheme or whatever, but it was the variant that made the most sense to me.

The `(lazy-arithmetic-sequence a b)` function produces (lazily) the infinite list `a, a+b, a+2b, a+3b, ...`

The `lazy-filter` function is the heart of the matter: it takes a predicate and a lazy list, and returns a lazy list with all the filtered elements. When forced, it goes through the input list finding the first element that should be included, and then returns that element consed with the lazy-filter of the rest of the list.

To test this out, I run this line:

```
(force (lazy-filter (lambda (v) (= v 1000000000)) (lazy-arithmetic-sequence 0 1)))
```

This is of course a rather pointless filter ("find the element with value one billion in this list from 0 to infinity"), but the point is to test the code out. The problem is that this consumes crazy amounts of memory. Within seconds its up to many gigabytes, and it shows no signs of slowing down, and I don't understand why.

I don't understand why the garbage collector doesn't reclaim the memory produced from the list. The loop in `lazy-filter` is tail-recursive, and there's no other references to the lazy list, so I feel like the GC should just gobble all that memory up. To make sure I even made a version that ran the garbage collector every iteration of the lazy-filter loop, and of course it didn't help.

My suspicion is that there's some reference hanging on to the head of the list that I'm not seeing. Like, the closure created by the `delay` in lazy-filter is somehow making the `seq` reference hang around, or something.

How can I rewrite this to not consume infinite amounts of memory?

I'm running Chez Scheme if that makes any difference, but I suspect that the problem is with me rather than the scheme implementation

Comment: `(cons (car forced) (lazy-filter pred (cdr forced)))` is not in tail call position. It's called *augmented tail call* - you could say it's almost like tail call, but it still has to stay on stack, because `lazy-filter` return value has to be cons'ed.

Comment: @rsm Yeah, but that branch is not ever taken in my example (i mean, it would be eventually, when we've counted to 1 billion, but I kill it long before that), and it's not even really recursive: lazy-filter returns immediately with a promise. The other branch, the loop, that's tail recursive (I checked by tracing the loop), and that's the one that is called. Is it still a problem if it's never taken?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a standard library, like [SRFI-41](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html)? Doing these things on your own is not easy as there are so many traps to fall though where you either loose caching or leak memory.

Comment: Also, if you are after doing it yourself you might get a kick out of the [SICP videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J_xL4IGhJA&list=PLE18841CABEA24090) where 6A+B coveres streams

Comment: @Sylwester it's for learning purposes mostly, for production use I would go with a library. But for learning, I prefer starting a bit-lower level to get an understanding of what's going on "behind the scenes". And I did learn something: Scheme might gobble up memory when you least expect it if you aren't careful. It's a good tip though, I'll compare the library implementation and see if I can figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to fix your problem:

```lisp
(define lazy-filter
  (lambda (pred seq)
    (delay
      (let loop ([sequence seq])
        ;; the following single line is added:   ------ NB!
        (set! seq sequence)
        (let ([forced (force sequence)])
          (cond [(null? forced) '()]
                [(pred (car forced))
                 (cons (car forced) (lazy-filter pred (cdr forced)))]
                [else (loop (cdr forced))]))))))
```

I tried `(force (lazy-filter (lambda (v) (= v 100000000)) (lazy-arithmetic-sequence 0 1)))` in Racket, and it finishes up, though slowly, running in constant memory as reported by my OS, returning

```lisp
'(100000000 . #<promise:unsaved-editor:12:4>)
```

Without the `(set! seq sequence)` the memory consumption reported by OS shoots up by several gigabytes and then Racket reports that it has run out of memory and the execution is aborted.

Some other re-writes of your code are found below, as are previous versions of this answer.

---

Trying your code in Racket's debugger, we get

[image]

`forced` and `sequence` are advancing along nicely, but `seq` is still at the start. And no wonder, nothing is changing it.

That's exactly as you suspected. A reference to the start of the sequence can not be released because `seq` is holding on to it until the result  is found and returned (as the `cons` pair). For 100 elements it's not an issue, but for 1 billion it surely is.

Float `loop` up and out of `lazy-filter` and the problem seems to be gone:

[image]

This code transformation technique is known as [lambda lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting).

The call to `loop` in `lazy-filter` becomes fully and manifestly *tail* because of it. Thanks to the tail call optimization the new call frame (for `loop`) can replace the old (for `lazy-filter`), which can now be discarded, together with its references into any data it held (here, `seq`).

The debugger snapshots show what's going on when the code is being debugged. Maybe without the debugging it is compiled differently, more efficiently. Maybe A Very Smart Compiler would in effect compile it by lambda lifting so the reference to `seq` could be relinquished, in the first code variant just as it is in the second. Looks like your Chez Scheme though compiles it just like Racket with debugging does (note, my version of Racket is old).

So it does seem like an *implementation* issue.

You will know for sure if you try the lambda-lifted code and see whether this fixes the problem:

```lisp
(define (lazy-filter pred seq)
    (delay (lazy-filter-loop pred seq)))

(define (lazy-filter-loop pred sequence)
        (let ([forced (force sequence)])
          (cond [(null? forced) '()]
                [(pred (car forced))
                  (cons (car forced) 
                          (lazy-filter pred (cdr forced)))]
                [else  (lazy-filter-loop pred (cdr forced))])))
```

Although one could reasonably expect of Chez compiler to do this on its own. Maybe you are running interpreted code? Maybe you have the debugging information included? These are the questions to consider.

Another way to restructure your code is

```lisp
(define lazy-filter
  (lambda (pred seq)
    (delay
      (let loop ([forced (force seq)])
          (cond [(null? forced) '()]
                [(pred (car forced))
                  (cons (car forced) 
                          (lazy-filter pred (cdr forced)))]
                [else  (set! seq (cdr forced))
                       (loop  (force (cdr forced)))])))))
```

---

*(the older version of the answer follows:)*

Let's see what *forcing* your expressions entails. I will use shorter names for your variables and functions, for more visual and immediate reading of the code.

We'll use [SSA program transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) to make a function's operational meaning explicit, and stop only on encountering a `delay` form.

You don't include your `delay` and `force` definitions, but we'll assume that `(force (delay <exp>)) = <exp>`:

```lisp
(define (lz-seq s n)  (delay  (cons s  (lz-seq (n s) n))))

(force (lz-seq s n))   =  (cons s  (lz-seq (n s) n))

    ;; lz-seq is a function, needs its args eval'd 
 =
    (cons s  (let* ([s2 (n s)])
                (lz-seq s2 n)))
 =
    (let* ([s2   (n s)] 
           [lz2  (delay  (cons s2  (lz-seq (n s2) n))) ]) 
       (cons  s  lz2))
```

We've discovered that forcing your kind of lazy sequence forces its *second* element as well as the first!

*(the following is incorrect:)*

<s>And this in fact exactly explains the behavior you're observing:</s>

```lisp
(force (lazy-filter (lambda (v) (= v 1000000000)) (lazy-arithmetic-sequence 0 1)))
```

*needs* to find out the second element of the filtered infinite stream before it can return the first `cons` cell of the result, but there's only one element in the filtered sequence, so the search for the second one never ends.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I really appreciate it! I didn't think anyone would respond to this! The definitions for delay and force are just the standard ones that come with Scheme R5RS, but you've got the idea. I don't think this is the right answer though: if you replace 1000000000 with 100, it returns immediately with the result `(100 . #<procedure>)`, as expected. It's true that lazy-infinite seq might need to calculate the next element (which is trivial, it's just the previous element plus one), but that doesn't mean lazy-filter has to.

Comment: well, have you seen the last version of the answer, with the fix? it worked for me, in Racket. have you tried it? did it work for you in Chez? if you don't like the `set!`, there's the lambda lifting transformation. is something still bothering you about this, or does it now just look too simple and obvious?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I hadn't even noticed that there was an update, I didn't get a notification for it and I've had a busy couple of days. I'll test it out tomorrow :). Thank you for your hard work. It strikes me that in the "lambda lifted" version, the function is a pure function and not a closure, since it doesn't enclose `pred`. I wonder if that has anything to do with it, that if you pass pred as an argument instead of as a variable in the enclosure, the compiler can lift it out more easily.

Comment: It's weird to me that seq lives on: it's not actually part of the closure, it's just an argument to the first invocation. You would think that when loop tail recurses, that reference would disappear, but apparently not. Tricky, this.

Comment: that's what lambda lifting *is*. you replace any closed over values with additional parameters and pass those values as arguments for those parameters. then there's no more closure, just lambda. and that simple lambda can be defined at the file's top level just as well.

Comment: a good compiler should've disappeared it by itself, one might argue. but only in a *compiled* code. :)

Comment: The only version that works for me is your final one, that deliberately resets `seq` (I just set it to `#f`, which also works). The lambda-lifted one still takes up oodles of memory in Chez, which almost feels like a bug (especially if it doesn't happen in Racket). It's very annoying that you have to use the imperative/mutating `set!` in what was supposed to be a purely functional exercise, but c'est la vie.

Comment: It feels very much to me like this SHOULD work: the loop is at tail position in the delay, and the loop itself is tail recursive, so the reference to the start of the list SHOULD be collected, since there's no way to reference it anymore. Thank you for all your help, this has been a very educational experience!

Comment: there *is* a way to reference it though: by referring to `seq`. Which *is* in scope in the delayed expression. Which does *not* refer to it! So perhaps a compiler ought to perform a code analysis to see what is or is not *actually referenced*. Lambda-lifted version definitely runs in constant memory in Racket, strange that in Chez it doesn't. Perhaps its tail call optimization is not up to the par, since it looks like it retains that call frame instead of discarding it. I'm almost sure that in Haskell the code comparable to your original one just runs as it should. They call it (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) wrapper/worker transform. ---- yep, setting `seq` to `#f` is even stronger.

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense. My intuition was that "if a closure doesn't explicitly reference something, it's not part of the closure", but presumably the compiler has to assume that EVERYTHING in the environment is enclosed. That makes sense, because you could convert a string to a symbol and reference through that, and there's no way (or at least extremely difficult) for the compiler to prove that that doesn't happen.